# SearchView not working if showAsAction is set to never

Tags: android, searchview

I would like to implement a `SearchView` in the `ActionBar` of an `Activity`. However, I don't want to start the search with the typical icon in the `ActionBar` using a `Menu`. I want to do it with a simple `Button`.

Here is my `Fragment`:

```
public class FragmentContacts extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private Button mButton;
    private MenuItem mSearchItem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ...

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mSearchItem != null) {
                    mSearchItem.expandActionView();
                }
            }
        });

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchItem.getActionView();
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(FragmentContacts.this);
            searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_users_hint));
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

}
```

And the `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.herald.main.TestActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search_user"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

This does not work, but if I set `app:showAsAction` to `collapseActionView|ifRoom` it does. The bad thing is that then the search icon appears and I don't want it.

Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/jb-mr2-release/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java) of SearchView#getSearchIconId, you can override R.attr.searchViewSearchIcon in your application theme, for instance with transparent image, and it should do the job. Other way - just create your own class that implement [CollapsibleActionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/CollapsibleActionView.html) and provide your own realization.

But in general it a strange idea - there is a guideline according to this behaviour and it's better to follow it if you'd like to have a successful application.